# Confusion around thread lock in the core program

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

My program consists of a main core function and a thread that was initiated inside that function to do some tasks (check order status and update the ledger). In my core program, im using objects of multiple classes hundreds of times and i need my thread to be able to make changes and add data to those objects that are shared from the core function. In that thread, i have implemented a thread lock to make sure everything runs smoothly. My question is whether i need to put a lock everytime i use the object in the core function or is it sufficient to only lock the resources in the thread?

My apologies in advance for not sharing the code, i cant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of holding a lock (i.e. having acquired and not yet released it) is that any other thread that tries to acquire **the same** lock will be blocked until the first thread has released the lock. In other words, at any given time at most one thread can hold the lock.

If only one thread uses the lock, nothing is achieved.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to avoid locking the resources everytime im calling them in my core program?